# SQL Server Management Studio won't connect to Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I've installed Visual Web Developer 2010, SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Management Studio 2008, using the MS Web Platform Installer 2.0. But whenever I wanna login, with ***Windows Authentication***, to SQL Server with the Sql Management Studio it throws me an error: **Cannot connect to (local)**

And then under that, it says that it can't find the server or it can't access it.

I used to use the Sql Management Studio 2005 before and I could connect easily. But with this version it seems there are some issues. Can someone help me, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check in the "SQL Server Configuration Manager" the instance is correct if you are trying to access.
If it is not the default instance, you must access by < computer_name >\< instance_name > (eg: MyComputer\SQLEXPRESS)

If still you do not connect, try the replace < computer_name > by "localhost" or "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Thanks, it works!!! I entered 'localhost/SQLEXPRESS' and it logged in. Thanks again...

Comment: you mean localhost\SQLEXPRESS (backslash) :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have multiple versions of SQL Server installed?

If so, you will need to specify the full instance name.