# Login failed for user 'someone'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string

I work on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R1 and visual studio 2010. 
My target is to clone a server to a new machine. However, after setting the application up and entering  "local/storytelling" in the browser's URL, the error msg appears. After google the possible mistake, I have set the authentication mode form  "Windows Authentication mode" to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".
But the error remains... And I have no more idea now.

Here is the error msg:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'storytelling'.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4846887
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +35
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject) +144
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart) +342
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +221
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +189
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +433
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +499
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
>      _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\storytelling\Default.aspx.vb:21
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

I don't know what's the problem to the code:(Source file: "Default.aspx.vb")

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)                      Handles Me.Load
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("StoryTelling2ConnectionString").ConnectionString)       
Dim cmmd As New SqlCommand   
Dim strSQL As String
conn.Open()
```

The error log highlight conn.Open() in red color. I guess it's probably I lost some steps as I cloned the server. But I have no idea what steps I ignored.
Please provide some suggestion. 
                                                             Thanks.

Comment: "Login failed for user 'storytelling'" Is that user present?

Comment: Yes, I open SSMS ,and in the Logins directory I add a user "storytelling", configuring its property the same with the user in the old machine.

Comment: Does the login map to the correct database user in the "User Mapping" tab?  What error do you get when you use this user to connect in SSMS?

Comment: No error occurs when I select the user and then log in. 
I can log in SSMS, but as I enter localhost/storytelling in the browser's url, the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally know what happened. Sorry for the poor representation of my problem. I take reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214625/sql-server-management-studio-wont-connect-to-sql-server) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001970/cannot-connect-to-local-sql-server-express-2008-r2), finding out that the windows server 2008 has installed an SQL Express edition for me. Nevertheless, I don't know at all, so I install another SQL Server. In this condition. I have two SQL server edition, and according to the thread [MSDN FORUM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/4675b346-8f36-468c-b706-e88af8f7879c/), the log in to the different server is quite different in the "Server Name" input.

In short, my connection string is always incompatible with the "Server Name" input, and thus the log in process always failed.